# Why recursion does not return a new object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a recursion function that iterates a tree and removes nodes where registry property is not true.

```
  function reduceNodesRegistry(source: any) {
     if (!source.registry) return source;

    return {
      ...source,
      children:
        source.children &&
        source.children
          .map(reduceNodesRegistry)
          .filter((item: any) => item.registry),
    };
  }

  console.clear();
  console.log("##########");
  console.log(reduceNodesRegistry(source));
```

Full code with model [by link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=65&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAzg9grgJwMYggXggbwFATxAIgDsBDAWxAIC5CCAaXfApACwEtgATBEI6iANqN8WYSMKkK-AoHQQQKwggHhA5gbhBAMiCBeEEDSIHIiBhEEDiIIAYQQIIggIRBAXCCAOEHpiRBKAAcQSNgDM2SAMLsuPPjTAEOBAGcSZeEgAjUE5%20VxJgKBDbJhgnfwh4xOSwvAIeAHM2KECATwAlEAcYBDB%20QODQ3OYfbl5%20IVz8HC67SUoaAkAEEHNTXUM1LR1AdhBFFQ1tPSMzKxtepigWGrAAOXIBwnklScWDEwtrJvX7Jxd3L1b6oJz1wjT2miykq96CCOiQLFPglvikwi0OJwAGrFNgAuIgl7XFgkKAAMTgwGAAGUQGQSEQwB4oE9GmDxAQ2ISQAgkkgwNj4MgDg0kb9AWwwABJam05xEmAZVk-Lr2EAkZAsUls0XAEilGm4iWsaUi5oOAkwHmuGCq8l2JLKlhouUFTwwYA1aQIAqRAAUAEYAGwAFjoEAAnE73Q6PQAOACUa1e%20RARRKCFKCOyavBrEhfg6%20vEPVedjYQMIAGYAOwAfQdwbTeRRUFx%20MJxL1xfCpABma%20MpD-WkgHwQQACIIA%20EDkoymS3Oq1jv0KxTK0dBNbyJTS2KQCQODoArAAGVdD0VgUpOfjL9fNABePM4IAAHvwHXvwQ42DSUNXJ2KK0SkAAtI%20n89r5PgqlgGl0sAAHVOSlAJnkvCkNTAFgAEEwECOE4D-EkaFTSdCDRDhgGtW0SDtAAmRdF3dXcIEI4iIGXAA6fCgwg8FsUCGAAGsQGAzhoPPeiKUYhAWIOfJcIIoiSPdcifSDb9xAAXykvBpO4tDi0pTMCFzPN8KLZTS3LAlnxQiBhTk2sohiccm2uFtBkAPBBABEQTt2wUZQ5HUPszhWS5jKnMAZznUBzxXL90NDcMx2BGMvMITdtxoXdIoIQ8iGPM8aCzbi8mvW8WXA%20KkifDw3ySj8aHw9LCF-f9%20WAziwLJYKoNg%20CEEQ5D%20CUmsCEwrEcMiPCswoh0XVKiAHTSyiaLoyK8l4-j2JqkayumpjWJ6u0VzE5cLwgLMnUk9DZJrA7XgAXWTaTjvO6SAG5sEYO68FcOAiHpNhBQgHhODgFAdhgY8oEqULIztWBEBQGgCVKANRHENwIDtABCEHmSokcI0h97wEQIhoCZFAbrEHgwCx6HxCosmkZQNV418XgqHJCmQCo6m2mxgAyVn6dxxnmb8ZMqPxBw7Q%20r6QB%20v6AdHSMAz59xgD-BA7TtTk8XBoh0bQAA%20CBlbIFGw0lyGfmuxhZMYJBBVgUAmdACU7QDG68HNohLcZy0CjtAgAGJvZ932CHts2LYtV2YHd4Xvt%20kB-v1tHga5gN7aAA)

Why function does not hide nodes where `registry: false`?

Edition 1:

```
  reduceNodesRegistry(source: any) {
    if (typeof source.registry !== "undefined" && source.registry === false)
      return source;

    return {
      ...source,
      children:
        source.children &&
        source.children
          .map(this.reduceNodesRegistry.bind(this))
          .filter(
            (item: any) =>
              typeof item.registry === undefined || item.registry === true
          ),
    };
  }
```

It does not hide nodes where `registry: false`.

Third I tried:

```
  reduceNodesRegistry(node: any) {
    return {
      ...node,
      children:
        node.children &&
        node.children
          .map(this.reduceNodesRegistry.bind(this))
          .filter(
            (node: any) => node.registry || node.registry === "undefined"
          ),
    };
  }
```

Comment: line 2 says if registry is false, return the input. Once a return is hit, execution in the function stops.

Comment: Okay, I tried to comment this line, it this case I get EMPTY result

Comment: Do you mean I should use `return;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source` doesn't have a truthy `registry`, so your `reduceNodesRegistry` return directly `source` without traversing the `children` property.

```
let source = {
    "name": "",
    "children": [...]
}
```

Comment: Yes, I got this. So, then I can  condition if (source.registry === undefined OR source.registry === true) in `.filter()` and remove the second line, right?

Comment: Check my editing. It still dont hide nodes where `registry: false`

Answer (score 1):

Your comparisons with undefined should be either of:

```
typeof item.registry === “undefined”
```

or

```
node.registry == undefined
```